# re.split('\n.+',content) outputs unexpected ['', '', '', '', '', '', '\n']

Tags: python, regex

Suppose such a following text

```
'\nModels: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class\nQuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions\nModel instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects\nMigrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations\nAdvanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions\nOther: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features\n'
```

The result I'd like to achieve is

```
['Models: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class',
 'QuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions',
 'Model instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects',
 'Migrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations',
 'Advanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions',
 'Other: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features',]
```

My first try is:

```
In [61]: re.split('\n', content)
Out[61]:
['',
 'Models: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class',
 'QuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions',
 'Model instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects',
 'Migrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations',
 'Advanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions',
 'Other: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features',
 '']
```

Nevertheless, when I tried

```
In [60]: re.split('\n.+',content)
Out[60]: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '\n']
```

The output is out of my expect.I cannot understand it.

In the example in [6.2. re—Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html)

```
re.split(r'\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
outputs ['Words', 'words', 'words', '']
not [',', ',', ',', ' ']
#why
re.split('\n.+',content)
outputs ['', '', '', '', '', '', '\n']
```

Comment: Because you have `\n` at start and end

Comment: Also `+` is greedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite obvious: `\n.+` matches anything starting with a newline character followed by one or more characters of any class but `.` will not match control characters such as newline.

So a match starts with the `\n` and ends one character before the next `\n`. Therefore, your split's separators are all the visible characters and such a split will produce empty strings because those empty strings are in between the separators.

Your input string starts and ends with a newline hence the first and last empty string after split with `\n`. Modify the pattern to

```
(?<!^)\n(?<!$)
```

to NOT match the leading and trailing newlines. This uses negative lookbehind and lookahead to exclude those first and last ones.

https://regex101.com/r/A2vIbu/1

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> txt
'\nModels: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class\nQuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions\nModel instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects\nMigrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations\nAdvanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions\nOther: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features\n'
```

You can do (I formatted this to look like your desired example...):

```
>>> [e for e in txt.split('\n') if e]
['Models: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class', 
 'QuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions', 
 'Model instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects', 'Migrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations', 
 'Advanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions', 
 'Other: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features']
```

Same method works for `re.split` as well:

```
>>> [e for e in re.split('\n+',txt) if e]
# same output...
```

Or, you can capture what you want vs splitting on what you don't want. In this case, use a look-behind to find the text after a `\n`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\n)([^\n]+)', txt)
# same output
```

Answer (score 0):

as mention by Garbage Collector, the problem with your first try is that your original text is surrounded by `\n`, so at the moment of the split you get an empty string as your first element to signal this fact, likewise for the end.

to solve this, you first need to remove those, that can be easily accomplished with the [.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = "\na a a\nb b b\nc c c\n"
>>> t.strip()
'a a a\nb b b\nc c c'
>>> re.split("\n",t.strip())
['a a a', 'b b b', 'c c c']
>>>
```

also for this task as described you don't need the `re` module, the [str class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) come with a plethora of method to handle a variety of common cases, for this one the [.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method would do it too

```
>>> t.strip().splitlines()
['a a a', 'b b b', 'c c c']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be a bit confused by the regex example from the text. `\W+` in a regex matches one or more *non-word* characters. So spaces, punctuation etc. are matched. Therefore `re.split` returns a list of words.

For your example to work, you just need to remove the `.*`.

e.g.

```
import re
content = '\nModels: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class\nQuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions\nModel instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects\nMigrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations\nAdvanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions\nOther: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features\n'

re.split(r'\n',content)

['', 'Models: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class', 'QuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions', 'Model instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects', 'Migrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations', 'Advanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions', 'Other: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features', '']
```

Also, if you know that you're going to start and finish with `\n`, you can just slice the blanks off:

```
re.split(r'\n',content)[1:-1]
['Models: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class', 'QuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions', 'Model instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects', 'Migrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations', 'Advanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions', 'Other: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features']
```